# inequality involving two dirichlet series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, generating-functions, dirichlet-series

Let $f\left( s \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ a_{n} \cdot \left( {\frac{1}{n^{s}}-\frac{1}{n^{1 - \operatorname{conj}\left( s \right)}}} \right) \right]$ and Let $g\left( s \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ c_{n} \cdot \left( {\frac{1}{n^{s}} - \frac{1}{n^{1 - \operatorname{conj}\left( s \right)}}} \right) \right]$ be two Dirichlet series with different intervals of convergence.
the question is:
if $\left| \left( \frac{a_{n}}{n^{s}} \right) \right| \le \left| \left( \frac{c_{n}}{n^{s}} \right) \right|$
does this means that $\left| f\left( s \right) \right| \le \left| g\left( s \right) \right|$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be great but unfotunately, it is not true.

Let's consider $a_n=n^s(-2t)^n/n!$ and $b_n=n^st^n/n !$

Then you have $|a_n|/n^s>|b_n|/n^s$ but you have also :

$$\sum_n a_n/n^s = e^{-2t}$$
And
$$\sum_n b_n/n^s = e^{t}. $$

Comment: if $a_n=z^n$ where $z$ is any complex number and $b_n=1$ then does the inequality applys?@Gaetano

Comment: Don't think so, if $z=-1$ you have $ |a_n|\geq|b_n|$ but the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: Sorry i missed something in my question you can see it after edit 
 @Gaetano

Comment: I missed that the inequality is for the absolute values of the functions